# A generic async method for requesting optionally paginated lists of different resources

Tags: c#, json, generics, pagination, async-await

I am accessing a REST API which returns a list of resources in JSON format:

```
{
    "products": [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

When the list is big (>50 items) the response becomes paginated and an additional `pagination` item is added to the root node of returned JSON like that:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "results" : 490,
        "page" : 1,
        "page_size" : 50,
        "pages" : 10
    },
    "products": [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

In order to cater for that I have a `PaginatedList` class (probably not the best name) which looks like that:

```
public class PaginatedList
{
    [JsonProperty("pagination")]
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
}
```

a `ProductList` class that looks like that:

```
public class ProductList : PaginatedList
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

a `Pagination` class like that:

```
public class Pagination
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public int Results { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page_size")]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pages")]
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}
```

To retrieve my resource I use:

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
    return getResourceAsync<ProductList>(productsResourceName).Result.Products;
}
```

and:

```
async Task<T> getResourceListAsync<T>(string resourceName)
    {
    var url = string.Concat(BaseUrl, resourceName);
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler)) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var resource = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(contentString);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Adding support for pagination inside the `GetProducts` method would be pretty easy but that would mean duplicating very similar code for every type of resource (products, customers, suppliers, etc). The question is, **how do I get the `getResourceListAsync` method so that it supports paginated and non-paginated lists *AND* works for different resources?**

Comment: Why are you waiting for an asynchronous method asynchronously? 1. It doesn't make sense, you're not getting any of the advantages of async. 2. It's pretty much asking for deadlocks to happen.

Comment: Also, did you already try to solve your problem somehow? What did you try? How did that fail?

Comment: @svick You are welcome to address your concerns in a nice elaborate answer. I'm just starting to play with async and clearly haven't got the best understanding of how to deal with it.

Comment: @svick I've had a nicely working synchronous solution based on RestSharp but translating it into async got me completely stuck. All advice highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give some more details i.e. by adding sample pagination to `GetProducts` method, which you consider to be then duplicated across various methods for different resources types? Why should it be duplicated? How is defined your `Product` type?

Comment: @PiotrZurek Hi, Could you please test my code in your own environment any then tell me the results ?
I've had tested my own code, and it was successful in my tests.

Comment: @YasserMoradi Sorry, I probably won't have time to test it before the weekend, but just looking at your code, it doesn't look like what I had in mind. First of all it's not a complete async and generic method. Secondly, what you didn't have to know, the API that I use is not very consistent so I can't assume that plural names will be correct so I simply use a constant (productsResourceName above) to define it. I'll try to play with it over the weekend though.

Comment: Thanks , no problem (-:
It's too easy to find that word using regular expressions.
Also with power of async,await and tasks, you can easily make that async method.
I've developed that code to generate the class you need on the fly, to solve the main problem.
Let me know if I could help you about other parts of problem.

Comment: Do you need to receive all pages in a single call? How about a loop iside your `using` block which repeats its body, adjusting the url to pass pagination parameters, until the last page is received?

Answer (score 1):

To make this scenario possible :

```
// supports both scenarios

            var json = @"{    'products': [        { Id : 1 , Name : 'A' },        { Id : 2 , Name : 'B' }    ] }";

            var results = Helper.ParseFromJsonResult<Product>(json);

            var anotherJson = @"{ 'pagination': {
                                                'results' : 490,
                                                'page' : 1,
                                                'page_size' : 50,
                                                'pages' : 10
                                            },
                                            'products': [
                                                { Id : 1 , Name : 'A' },        { Id : 2 , Name : 'B' } 
                                            ]}";

            var anotherResults = Helper.ParseFromJsonResult<Product>(anotherJson);
```

You can use this codes :

```
public static class Helper
    {
        private static readonly PluralizationService _NameService =
            PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-us"));
        // Provides Plural names [ products for Product ]
        // to determinate the name of the result for example products for Product class

        private static ModuleBuilder _ModuleBuilder;

        static Helper()
        {
            var asmName = new AssemblyName();

            asmName.Name = "MyHelpers";

            AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

            _ModuleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyHelpers");

            // Assembly to put runtime generated classes to that.
        }

        private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Type> _HelpersCache = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        public static List<T> ParseFromJsonResult<T>(String json)
        {
            Type resultType = null;

            var entityType = typeof(T);

            var pluralName = _NameService.Pluralize(entityType.Name).ToLowerInvariant();
            // products for Product class

            if (_HelpersCache.ContainsKey(entityType))
            {
                // better performance
                resultType = _HelpersCache[entityType];
            }
            else
            {
                // need another runtime generated class 
                // result :
                /* public class products
                   {
                      public List<Product> products;
                   }
                */

                TypeBuilder resultTypeBuilder = _ModuleBuilder.DefineType(pluralName, TypeAttributes.Public);

                FieldBuilder field = resultTypeBuilder.DefineField(pluralName, typeof(List<T>), FieldAttributes.Public);

                resultType = resultTypeBuilder.CreateType();

                _HelpersCache.Add(entityType, resultType);
            }

            Object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, resultType);

            return (List<T>)resultType.GetField(pluralName).GetValue(result); // get products field value
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps, Let me know if you want more information

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. Was stuck in the same one actually. What I ended up doing was an interface that my classes i want to paginte implement. As I did this for export of data it is called IExportable. This thing returns a PagedResult and takes a IPagedRequest.

So the point is that my code in the task is just working with interface and does not actually know what the end type is. PagedResult is a type with generics. 
Hope it helps, trying to write this from top of my head without the source.